# Is there a way to turn my device on while it's stuck in a boot loop due to a broken power key?

Tags: adb, boot-loop, nexus-5

I have this old LG Nexus 5 with a broken power key laying around and I want to access storage now. Problem is whenever I hold down the power button it goes into an infinite boot loop. Gets to various lengths of the android boot animation but always fails and starts over.

I know for a fact that the phone has USB debugging enabled. 
Phone is not rooted.
I have tried using ADB, however `adb devices` doesn't list anything and connecting it via USB automatically starts the boot loop without me even holding down the power button.

Is there anything I can do other than take it to some shop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your phone turn on when you charge it? If yes, you could turn it on via power cable instead of power button. That's *if* the power button does ever release itself. If not, the only option is to fix the hardware. Either open up the phone yourself or take it to a store.

Comment: Heh I managed to turn it on after 30 minutes of pressing down the broken button and then had just enough time to copy storage to my pc before it shut itself down on its own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got lucky and managed to turn it on for just long enough to get my data.